# How to delete an old Closed Question that is spread across two sites?

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions

[Inexpensive beach locations to learn surfing as a newbie?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53803/inexpensive-beach-locations-to-learn-surfing-as-a-newbie) [closed more than a year ago] is both on TSE and The Great Outdoors, with the latter seemingly having rejected migration there.

How might one, with enough reputation, vote to delete this?

Comment: Why do you want it deleted? Why this one specifically, as opposed to the hundreds of others that have been closed.

Comment: I don't think it's in the way - it has an answer with an upvote.  Questions closed without answers tend to get auto-deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat to my surprise, the post in question was automatically deleted with a note as below:

> deleted by Community♦ Dec 10 at 1:01 (RemoveRejectedMigrations)
>
> This question was automatically deleted. Please see the help center for more information.

I take it the year was 2016, though the post was dated 2015.

Comment: Looks like the reason was a clean up of rejected migrations, not a standard closure. Still interesting though.

Answer (score 3):

[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222) notes:

> ## How can a post be deleted?
>
> ### By a user:
>
> 1. **You** can typically delete your own posts at will; for exceptions, see When can’t I delete my own post? below. To delete a post, just use the delete link below it.
> 2. **Moderators** can delete any post instantly.
> 3. **Users with reputation ≥ 2k** (more precisely, the [edit privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit); 1k on beta sites) [can cause](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145292) automatic deletion of a post if they choose recommend deletion from within the low-quality review queue.
> 4. **Users with reputation ≥ 10k** (more precisely, the [moderator-tools privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools); 2k on beta sites) can vote to delete questions that have been [closed/on-hold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/) for 48 hours. It takes three votes to delete; [more if the question is popular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071), but ten votes at most.
> 5. **Users with reputation ≥ 20k** (more precisely, the [trusted-user privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user); 4k on beta sites) are not subject to the 48-hour waiting period for deleting closed questions with a score of −3 or lower. They may also delete answers of score −1 or lower. It takes three votes to delete an answer.
>
> (All emphasis and links present in the original.)

Number 1 does not apply. Number 3 only applies to answers. Numbers 2, 4 and 5 are valid, however. Thus:

- it either takes a moderator agreeing with you that the question should be deleted; or
- a certain number of users with more than 10 krep need to agree with you.

For the latter, there should be a little *delete* link in line with *share, edit, reopen,* etc.

[Another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071) explains the number of deletion votes required for ‘popular’ questions:

> The new rules (also apply to undelete votes):
>
> - 10k rep users get **5** deletion votes per day on questions they don't own - [deletion rules on questions one does own are still in effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222).
> - Popular questions require more deletion votes to be deleted, at a ratio of 20:1 - a question's popularity is defined as: question score + top-scored answer score.  For example, a question with (question score 15 + top answer score 5 = 20) will require 4 deletion votes (3 base votes + 1 popularity vote).
> - The maximum number of delete votes needed will not exceed 10.
>
> Note that the above rules apply only to questions; answers take 3 votes, regardless of score.

The question in question (pun intended) has a score of +6 and one answer with a score of +1. Since 6 + 1 < 20, three deletion votes from the community with more than 10 krep should remove it.

Comment: @pnuts Checking a random old (January 2014) closed question with a positive score (not a dupe), I saw the delete link there, so I wouldn’t know why it should not be around for that question here.

Comment: @pnuts If it truly is special, only a custom mod flag will do the job (or asking the mods in chat).

Comment: @pnuts Very weird ô.o

Comment: @pnuts where did you ask me? And remember, there's a process for this - flagging. Sometimes we miss comments in chat/elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry, missed it - I'd seen the line with your direct @ tag but not the ones below.  BTW every time a new meta post is written, we get a notification as mods, I see you were wondering.
But sometimes we don't have the time to act on them immediately. I'd love to get to some tag re-taggings when I get a chance, but at present I'm just keeping on top of the main site stuff.

Comment: pnuts note that there are 4 mods, but for some reason I tend to get pinged ;)  Maybe being the most active mod on the site is a curse ;)  But I believe new mods are added on a traffic/activity level by SE, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that posts with an answer are not automatically deleted.

This post has upvotes and an answer, so while closed, it remains for posterity.